# Where in the scriptures is the present day Agnihotra?

Tags: vedas, yajna

By present day Agnihotra I mean, the one performed during sunrise and sunset involving burning cow dung along with rice.
As far as I believe there seems to be no such practice mentioned anywhere in the Ramayana or Mahabharata. (Yes, the term 'Agnihotra' is mentioned, but it certainly doesn't seem to be the above practice).
Is the above practice mentioned in the Vedas or related scriptures?